# copying an array without the first object via the map () function

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

Its my code!!!

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var b = a.map((n) => {
    if (n !== 0) {
        return n;
    }
});
```

Array B must copy all elements from array A except for one object that does not match the condition.

Result: the array copies everything, and instead of 0 it writes 'undefined'.

Should be: array B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

Comment: `var b = a.slice(1)`

Comment: `map` is the wrong method. Check the list of possible array methods again. There is another one with a name that should make it sound like the obvious choice :)

Comment: I have no right to modify array A, for this I use copy

Comment: `slice()` does not modify the original.

Comment: Neither my nor Taplar's suggestion modify the array, though.

Comment: Try `Array#filter`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array#filter` instead.

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var b = a.filter((n) => {
    return n !== 0;
});

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a spread operator, and then slice the new array.

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var b = [...a].slice(1);

console.log(b); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I would not recommend Array#map in this case, because there's no reason to iterate through each element of the array. With the spread operator, we can make a full copy of the original array, and mutate the new copy to exclude the first element.

If you have to use the Array#filter method, you can use it like so:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var b = a.filter((n, i) => {
    if (i > 0) {
      return n
    }
});

console.log(b);
```

This would remove the first element of your array.